# Add icon in PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, propertygrid, syncfusion

I'm trying to display the icon for every cell in my propertygrid as the image shown below

[image]

so my question is, is it possible to make it in a WPF PropertyGrid? 
if yes, then how?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We have considered “Add icon in PropertyGrid”  as feature and it will be available in any of our upcoming releases.